# convert index of series object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series object in panda

```
330    0.064591
331   -0.705979
332   -1.516967
333   -3.477834
334   -0.605740
335    0.457864
336   -0.374490
```

I have a dataframe, df, that is of the same length. I'd like to convert the index of the series to the dates in df so that I can compare the two. How would I do that?

Comment: `df['new_col'] = s.index`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
>>> s
330    0.064591
331   -0.705979
332   -0.516967
dtype: float64
>>> df
                                   A
2013-11-25 07:49:52.584591  0.064591
2013-11-26 07:49:52.584626 -0.705979
2013-11-27 07:49:52.584633 -1.516967

>>> df_froms = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=df.columns)
>>> df_froms.index = df.index
>>> df == df_froms
                                A
2013-11-25 07:49:52.584591   True
2013-11-26 07:49:52.584626   True
2013-11-27 07:49:52.584633  False
```